# second derivative of fadeeva function from scipy.special

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to calculate a second derivative of the `Fadeeva` function `special.wofz`. The `Fadeeva` function is closely related to the error function. So if someone is more familiar with erf the answers are appreciated. 
Here is the code to find the second derivative of `wofz`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import wofz


def Z(x):
    return wofz(x)

## first derivative of wofz (analytically)
def Zp(x):
    return -2/1j/np.pi**0.5 - 2*x*Z(x)

##second derivative (analytically)
def Zpp(x):
    return (Z(x)+x*Zp(x))*x

x = np.float64(np.linspace(1e4,14e4,1000))

plt.plot(x, Zpp(x).imag,"-")

Zpp_num=np.diff(Zp(x))/np.diff(x)  ##calc numerically the second derivative
plt.plot(x[:-1],Zpp_num.imag)
```

the code produces the next figure:

[image: result of second derivative of the wofz]

Obviously, there is something seriously wrong with the analytic calculations. The formula I've been using is correct. It must be some numerical issue.

**Q:** Can someone tell me what causes this behavior? Is it due to precision of the wofz function? Does anyone know the algorithm to calculate the `wofz`? How big the argument can be to produce a reliable result? I couldn't find any information on it. Also, I know that I can use an asymptotic approximation for `wofz` to find the second derivative but I would like to use `scipy` if it is possible.

Comment: You have `wofz,` `wofz`, and (my favourite), `worf` in your question. Should those all be `wofz`?

Comment: It doesn't change your problems with numerical accuracy, but `Zpp` should return `-2*(Z(x) + x*Zp(x))`, not `(Z(x)+x*Zp(x))*x`.

Comment: @clwainwright, yup, I got that too.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thanks for pointing out the typos. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on @Andras Deak's answer, you can figure out the high-x expansion analytically, and then interpolate between it and the scipy function using some simple smoothing. There are actually two terms that cancel in the high-x expansion, so you've got to be a little careful.

Here's what I got for an answer:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import wofz


def Z(x):
    return wofz(x)

## first derivative of wofz (analytically)
def Zp(x):
    return -2/1j/np.pi**0.5 - 2*x*Z(x)

def dawsn_expansion(x):
    # Accurate to order x^-9, or, relative to the first term x^-8
    # So when x > 100, this will be as accurate as you can get with
    # double floating point precision.
    y = 0.5 * x**-2
    return 1/(2*x) * (1 + y * (1 + 3*y * (1 + 5*y * (1 + 7*y))))

def dawsn_expansion_drop_first(x):
    y = 0.5 * x**-2
    return 1/(2*x) * (0 + y * (1 + 3*y * (1 + 5*y * (1 + 7*y))))

def dawsn_expansion_drop_first_two(x):
    y = 0.5 * x**-2
    return 1/(2*x) * (0 + y * (0 + 3*y * (1 + 5*y * (1 + 7*y))))

def blend(x, a, b):
    # Smoothly blend x from 0 at a to 1 at b
    y = (x - a) / (b - a)
    y *= (y > 0)
    y = y * (y <= 1) + 1 * (y > 1)
    return y*y * (3 - 2*y)

def g(x):
    """Calculate `x + (1-2x^2) D(x)`, where D(x) is the dawson function"""
    # For x < 50, use dawsn from scipy
    # For x > 100, use dawsn expansion
    b = blend(x, 50, 100)
    y1 = x + (1 - 2*x**2) * special.dawsn(x)
    y2 = dawsn_expansion_drop_first(x) - dawsn_expansion_drop_first_two(x) * 2*x**2
    return b*y2 + (1-b)*y1

def Zpp(x):
    # only return the imaginary component
    return -4j/np.pi**0.5 * g(x)

x = np.logspace(0, 5, 2000)
dx = 1e-3
plt.plot(x, (Zp(x+dx) - Zp(x-dx)).imag/(2*dx))
plt.plot(x, Zpp(x).imag)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

which produces the following plot:
[image: fadeeva derivative comparison]

The blue line is the numerical derivative, and the green line is the derivative using the expansion. The latter actually has much better behavior at large x.

Comment: Good one! I didn't pursue the expansion approach since OP wanted to avoid that, but this turned out much better than I anticipated:)

Comment: @clwainwright thanks for the solution. Can `bend(x,a,b)` simply return y?

Comment: @clwainwright so the problem with the analytic expression for the second derivative is that the main terms don't cancel each other exactly due to round off errors creating the numerical noise. In your solution you set the main terms to zero to avoid this problem. Do I get it correctly?

Comment: @user3388921 That's basically correct, although the problem is more that the main terms *do* cancel exactly and that the left-over terms just don't have that many bits of precision. For example, consider the expression `3000000000001/3000000000000 - 1`. We know this should be equal to `1e-12 / 3`, but python will spit out something like `3.3328e-13`. The one goes away exactly, but there were only a few bits of precision left to represent the left-over part, so everything after the first few digits is garbage. You'll run into this loss of precision whenever you subtract two similar numbers.

Comment: @user3388921 just to add, this process is called "loss of precision" and can cause [many serious problems](http://ta.twi.tudelft.nl/nw/users/vuik/wi211/disasters.html).

Answer (score 4):

As you suspect, the problem is of numerical origin when computing your derivative. The correct second derivative, as [@clwainwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33246398/second-derivative-of-fadeeva-function-from-scipy-special#comment54298847_33246398) has already noted in a comment, is

```
Zpp = -2*(Z(x) + x*Zp(x))
```

The imaginary parts of the two terms behave like this:

[image: problem]

showing that you have two small quantities which are *almost* equal, and you compute their difference.

Going more into details,

```
Zpp = -2*(1-2*x**2)*Z(x) - 4j/sqrt(pi)*x
```

the imaginary part of which is

```
Im(Zpp) = - 4*x/sqrt(pi) - 2*(1-2*x**2)*Im(Z)
```

and `Im(Z)` is proportional to the Dawson function `D` (`scipy.special.dawsn`),

```
Im(Z) = 2/sqrt(pi) * D
```

The problem with this is that you have

```
Im(Zpp(x)) = -4/sqrt(pi)*( x - 2*x**2*dawsn(x) ) - 4/sqrt(pi)*dawsn(x)
```

Why this is a problem is because [the asymptotic expansion of the Dawson function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function) starts as

```
D(x) ~ 1/(2x) + ...
```

the leading term of which is eaten by the first term of `Im(Zpp(x))`, and the small corrections give the function its value (actually, the leading term is the `1/(2x)` in the last term of `Im(Zpp(x))`.

So the problem is inherent in the analytical expression of `Zpp`. You can try to reshape the analytical expression to get rid of this numerical problem (specifically, loss of precision), but it won't be easy. You could also try utilizing `sympy`. I've been trying both for a while now, with no success. It might still be possible.